# Grails GORM double nested association query

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following domain classes (with relevant properties):

```
class Order {
    static belongsTo = [ restaurant : Restaurant ] 
}

class Restaurant {
    static belongsTo = [ country : Country ] 
}

class Country { 
}
```

The table structure is fine and data is generated correctly. But when I try to get a ***list of all orders whose restaurant belongs to a specific country***, I only get ONE order.

Here is a test that fails to prove that:

```
def testOrdersByCountry(){

    given:
        def c = new Country().save()
        def r = new Restaurant(country:c).save()
        new Order(restaurant:r).save()
        new Order(restaurant:r).save()
        new Order(restaurant:r).save()

    when:
        def orders = Order.withCriteria {
            restaurant {
                country {
                    eq 'id', c.id
                }
            }
        }

    then:
        orders.size() == 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You many need

```
static hasMany = [orders : Order]
```

in class `Restaurant`